# Json result get values

Tags: javascript, json

from controller Json is returned and in function i get an object which contains

```
{
    "readyState":4,
    "responseText":"{\"Success\":0,\"Failed\":0}",
    "responseJSON":{
        "Success":0,
        "Failed":0
    },
    "status":200,
    "statusText":"OK"
}
```

How can I take Success and Failed values?

data.Successand JSON.parse(data) is not working

Comment: `JSON.parse(a.responseText).Success`

Comment: Please define "is not working". Why not? You get an error? You get unexpected results? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to parse that because that **IS** already an object:

```
var obj = {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Success\":0,\"Failed\":0}","responseJSON":{"Success":0,"Failed":0},"status":200,"statusText":"OK"};
var failed = obj.responseJSON.Failed;
var success = obj.responseJSON.Success;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json_data = '{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Success\":0,\"Failed\":0}",
 "responseJSON":{"Success":0,"Failed":0},"status":200,"statusText":"OK"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json_data);


alert(obj.responseJSON.Success);  // for success that in responseJSON
alert(obj.responseJSON.Failed);
```

Thanks :)